# During runtime: write, compile and use C# code?

Tags: c#, dll, compiler-construction, runtime

Hi I am trying to find a way of executing code generated at runtime, without restarting the program.

My current workflow:

1. User uses my program to create some diagrams
2. User presses `compile` and C# code is generated from the users diagrams
3. The C# code is placed in a code file which exists in my project's hierarchy. The program is then restarted in order to use the newly generated code.

What I'm after though is changing Step 3, so I don't have to restart the program. Something like:

1. The C# code is run through the C# compiler which generates a DLL.

   - any errors are shown to the user
2. The DLL is then loaded into the program
3. Setup some links to the codes methods, so I can pass data to it and get output data

if this would work?

Comment: You want the [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) class. There's a reasonably good example on that help page, and there are many other examples available online.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It is intended for compiling a code in memory.